# Strange results of mysql query with GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Just wondering if anyone can spot anything obviously wrong here. I'm getting strange results with a SELECT in MySQL. I can't see anything wrong with the query so I wondered if some data is throwing it out, but the data does look ok.. So I guess my sql has gone a bit wrong!

I have 2 tables, CITY and WEATHER:

```
CITY:
  CITY_ID    INT(3)
  CITY_NAME  VARCHAR(100)

WEATHER:
  CITY_ID   INT(3)
  SDATE     DATETIME
  TEMP      INT(3)
  RAIN      INT(3)
```

The CITY table is very small; one row per defined city.

The WEATHER table has many rows; it has forecasts (several times per day) for each city. Also holds historical forecasts, so there's data in there going back a few months.

I want to see a summary for each city for each month, on each line. 
I want all cities info for a month, then the previous month etc.
Within each month I want the results order by temperature (descending) and then rain (descending).

So, my query:

```
 SELECT     a.city_name                   as CITY
          , DATE_FORMAT(b.sdate, '%M %Y') as MONTH
          , ROUND(avg(b.temp))            as AVG_TEMP_C
          , SUM(b.rain)                   as RAIN
 FROM       CITY a , WEATHER b
 WHERE      a.city_id = b.city_id
 GROUP BY   a.city_name , DATE_FORMAT(b.sdate, '%M %Y')
 ORDER BY   sdate desc,  ROUND(avg(b.temp)) desc , SUM(b.rain) desc;
```

Results I would expect:

```
CITY         MONTH  TEMP   RAIN
ISTANBUL     June   20     0
MUNICH       June   15     9
PARIS        June   15     7
MILAN        June   14     8
ISTANBUL     May    19     22
etc.
```

Results I get:

```
CITY         MONTH  TEMP   RAIN
MUNICH       June   15     9
MILAN        June   14     8
ISTANBUL     June   20     0
PARIS        June   15     7
ISTANBUL     May    19     22
etc.
```

Like I say, the data *looks* ok, so I guess I've missed something amongst all the formatting, the join, group and order by..

Comment: Can you set up http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ example with your sample data set

Comment: Perhaps you need to order by `DATE_FORMAT(b.sdate, '%M %Y')` instead of the `date` by itself.  Sample data would help to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks for replying but ordering by DATE_FORMAT(b.sdate, '%M %Y') desc would order by month alphabetically (so May, March, June, April)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query with an explicit join and more sensible table aliases (table abbreviations rather than arbitrary letters):

```
 SELECT     c.city_name                   as CITY,
            DATE_FORMAT(w.sdate, '%M %Y') as MONTH,
            ROUND(avg(w.temp))            as AVG_TEMP_C,
            SUM(w.rain)                   as RAIN,
 FROM       CITY a JOIN
            WEATHER w
            ON c.city_id = w.city_id
 GROUP BY   c.city_name , DATE_FORMAT(w.sdate, '%M %Y')
 ORDER BY   sdate desc,  ROUND(avg(w.temp)) desc , SUM(w.rain) desc;
```

The first column in the `order by` is `sdate`.  However, that is not included in your `group by` clause.  So, a value of `sdate` from an indeterminate row is chosen for each city by MySQL (in other databases, this would produce an error).

Instead, change your `order by` to use the month and year:

```
 ORDER BY   year(sdate) desc,  month(sdate) desc, ROUND(avg(w.temp)) desc , SUM(w.rain) desc;
```

Comment: Surely in this situation using `ORDER BY   year(sdate) desc,  month(sdate) desc` is still going to result in an indeterminate rows value of sdate being used for the sort? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Bingo! Thanks very much! So, just to confirm, my version of the join is ok, the problem is in the ORDER BY of the date? I did think that if it was Oracle (for example) that it would have produced an error. Having not thrown an error, I gathered that the syntax was "ok" for mysql.. but of course, just because the syntax is "ok" it doesn't mean that it will do what you wanted it to! I understand why just having "ORDER by sdate" wasn't working, but I still don't really get how using the year() and month() have fixed this though.

Comment: I had missed something. While it uses an indeterminate rows value of sdate, any of those values of sdate that it would use would share the same month and year.

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting by sdate, which is in the aggregated result table, but not subject of an aggregate function. Therefore mysql takes any sdate value which matches the other conditions (probably the first one?) and sorts by this value.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to also bring back the max date for each city / month, and then use that in the ORDER BY (formatted to CCYYMM format) to get them in the right order.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT a.city_name as CITY , 
        DATE_FORMAT(b.sdate, '%M %Y') as MONTH , 
        MAX(b.sdate) AS max_date,
        ROUND(avg(b.temp)) as AVG_TEMP_C , 
        SUM(b.rain) as RAIN 
FROM CITY a 
INNER JOIN WEATHER b 
ON a.city_id = b.city_id 
GROUP BY a.city_name , MONTH
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(max_date, '%Y%m') desc, AVG_TEMP_C desc , RAIN desc;
```

or slightly different like this:-

```
SELECT a.city_name as CITY , 
        DATE_FORMAT(b.sdate, '%M %Y') as MONTH , 
        MAX(b.sdate) AS max_date,
        ROUND(avg(b.temp)) as AVG_TEMP_C , 
        SUM(b.rain) as RAIN 
FROM CITY a 
INNER JOIN WEATHER b 
ON a.city_id = b.city_id 
GROUP BY a.city_name , MONTH
ORDER BY YEAR(max_date) desc, MONTH(max_date) desc, AVG_TEMP_C desc , RAIN desc;
```